# Fast list update using list of indices with repetitions

Tags: list-manipulation, index

I want to update a vector like this:

```
list = {0, 0, 0, 0};
updval = {1, 1, 1};
updind = {2, 2, 3};
list[[updind]] += updval;
list
```

The result is `{0, 1, 1, 0}`, but should be `{0, 2, 1, 0}`.
The problem are the repeated indices in `updind`.

How can one do this correctly and fast?

The lists are on the order of kilobytes, but many such assignments need to be done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following will do it:

```
MapThread[(list[[#1]] += #2) &, {updind, updval}]
list
(*  {0, 2, 1, 0}  *)
```

This will be much faster on large arrays of machine-size integers:

```
Compile[
  {{list0, _Integer, 1}, {updind, _Integer, 1}, {updval, _Integer, 1}},
  Module[{list = list0},
   MapThread[(list[[#1]] += #2) &, {updind, updval}];
   list
   ]][list, updind, updval]
```

Comment: Thanks. I had a similar solution using `Scan`, but way too slow, so I then used `Compile` with `For` loops, which should be comparable to your second suggestion. I'm still wondering though whether there is a clever Mathematica construct that is significantly faster than the Scan/MapThread at least.